# Html javascript Submit different form same data type, 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so this is a bit confusing to explain but basically, I am creating a checkout page which users can either choose "delivery" or "Pickup", once chosen it 'unhides' the corresponding form which once filled out will send data to the next page. The problem is that I want to use the same id's for both forms but just add an address to the delivery one but it seems like it will only take data from the first/top form which is the takeaway-

```js
function Delivery1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Pickup");
  var y = document.getElementById("Delivery");
  var w = document.getElementById("btn1");
  var z = document.getElementById("btn2");

  if (y.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "block";
    w.style.backgroundColor = "#b20c0c";
    z.style.backgroundColor = "#cc1400";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";

  }
}


function Pickup1() {
  var y = document.getElementById("Delivery");
  var x = document.getElementById("Pickup");
  var w = document.getElementById("btn1");
  var z = document.getElementById("btn2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.backgroundColor = "#b20c0c";
    w.style.backgroundColor = "#cc1400";

  } else {
    z.style.backgroundColor = "#cc1400";
    x.style.display = "none";

  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="Delivery1()" class="btn" style="height:90px; width: 180px">Delivery</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="Pickup1()" class="btn" style="height:90px; width: 180px">Pickup</button>
</center>

<div id="Pickup" style="display: none;">
  <form action="order.html" method="post" id="checkout-order-form">


    <fieldset id="fieldset-billing">
      <legend>Pickup</legend>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" data-type="string" data-message="This field cannot be empty" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" data-type="expression" data-message="Not a valid phone address" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="country">Select Store</label>
        <select name="country" id="country" data-type="string" data-message="This field cannot be empty">
          <option value="">None</option>
          <option value="Leopold">Leopold</option>

        </select>


    </fieldset>
    <p><input type="submit" id="submit-order" value="Submit" class="btn" /></p>
    </div>
  </form>



  <div id="Delivery" style="display: none;">

    <form action="order.html" method="post" id="checkout-order-form">

      <fieldset id="fieldset-shipping">

        <legend>Delivery</legend>

        <div>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" data-type="string" data-message="This field cannot be empty" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="email">Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" data-type="expression" data-message="Not a valid phone number" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="address">Address</label>
          <h3>(Must be in or in neighbouring suburbs of leopold no more than 10km)</h3>
          <input type="text" name="address" id="address" data-type="string" data-message="This field cannot be empty" />
        </div>


      </fieldset>

      <p><input type="submit" id="submit-order" value="Submit" class="btn" /></p>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>



</div>

<footer id="site-info">
  Copyright &copy; Fu Chinese
</footer>
```

If its needed i can post the javascript form but its quite long. If anyone can help me with a solution or easier way to do this that would be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have more than one element with the same Id.

The purpose of the ID is to identify elements on page, therefore, you can have only one element per ID.

You can have multiple elements with the same "name" but not with the same ID.

To solve your problem, do the following:

1. Put a different ID for each form.
2. Put the attribute `form` in the `input` tag in your form.

Form 1:

`<form action="order.html" method="post" id="checkout-order-form-billing">`

`<input type="submit" id="submit-order" value="Submit" class="btn" form="checkout-order-form-billing" />`

Form 2:

`<form action="order.html" method="post" id="checkout-order-form-shipping">`

`<input type="submit" id="submit-order" value="Submit" class="btn" form="checkout-order-form-shipping" />`

This way, the `input` tag knows which form to submit.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried having it such as "sEmail" for one of the forms and even tried to add it to the data area  `
     var html = "<div class='detail'>";
      html += "<h2>Billing and Shipping</h2>";
      html += "<ul>";
      html += "<li>" + name + "</li>";
      html += "<li>" + email + "</li>";
      html += "<li>" + country + "</li>";
      html += "<li>" + address + "</li>"; 

      html += "</ul></div>";` but it still favors the pickup form

Comment: @RedstoneMaina. I updated the answer and put a code example.

Comment: Ah makes sense, but when it gets to this.$.... = this.$element.find("...") can they have the same value? if not will I have to change/duplicate all items that refer to the this.$... I.e `   this.$checkoutOrderForm = this.$element.find( "#checkout-order-form-shipping" );
   this.$checkoutOrderForm = this.$element.find( "#checkout-order-form-billing" );  `

Comment: @RedstoneMaina Assuming you are trying to get the form element via javascript/jQuery you have to specify the form ID, so if you want to get the `#checkout-order-form-shipping` form you have to use the `this.$element.find( "#checkout-order-form-shipping" );` and if you want the `#checkout-order-form-billing` use `this.$element.find( "#checkout-order-form-billing" ); `.